# How to remove a message from the JMS queue (Message Processor) at a flow FAULT?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Normally when an error occurs in processing (MessageProcessor) JMS queue and goes to faultSequence and is not removed from the queue. My doubt is in some fault codes that I need to remove the message from the JMS queue even being a FAULT. Could you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Message Forwarding Processor, You can not remove the message out from the Queue. It will be keep try until it send the message out successfully.

You can use Message Sampling Processor for your use case, Sample Message processor send the message only once and remove it from the queue. If you found it as a faulty attempt, you can re insert the message into the queue again based on Fault code that you got it in faultSequence.﻿

Answer (score 1):

You probably run your processor under transaction, having the following within your JMS listener config of axis2.xml:

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">true</parameter>
```

Changing this parameter to false will make your failed messages removed from the queue they were read from.

Comment: When "transport.jms.SessionTransacted" is false will remove the message from queue regardless of failure of the backend.

Comment: Yes, I expect right the same. But the problem is with failed messages as I see.